# How do I change square connect permissions on PAT?

Tags: square-connect

I'm connecting to the v1 connect API to grab inventory for a couple items in my store.  I'm using the PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN

The end point is connecting fine, but it's returning a blank dataset, presumably because when i connected to v1/me

I only have the following permissions :

"account_capabilities":["EMPLOYEE_MANAGEMENT","TIMECARD_MANAGEMENT"]

Inventory needs "ITEMS_READ", is there a way to change this without having to use OAuth, or am i stuck making an oAuth request everytime i need to pull inventory?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is occurring because your Square account is a [Multilocation account](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-multilocation). Because of this, you need to access Connect API endpoints slightly differently:

1. Use the [List Locations](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-locations) endpoint (`/v1/me/locations`) to get the `id` for each of your business's individual locations.
2. To access item, inventory, or payment information for one of your individual locations, provide that location's `id` as the value of the `merchant_id` path parameter (instead of providing `me`) in your request.

Note that the `account_capabilities` listed by `/v1/me` are different from capabilities described by [OAuth permissions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#permissionscope). Regardless, your personal access token grants you complete access to all endpoints for your own Square account.

Comment: Thanks, this helped :)